# How to keep the original indices in a numpy array output from predict function

Tags: pandas, numpy

I've trained an xgb model and call a predict function on the test dataset

```
xg_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

preds = xg_reg.predict(X_test)
```

However, the resultant `preds` variable is a `numpy` array where indices are reset to `0-101`

As my `y_test` is a pandas dataframe with random indices from splitting it with `train_test_split from (sklearn.model_selection)` I can't actually map or append the resulting predicted values to the test dataframe.

Is there a way to retain the original indexing in predicted array?

Answer (score 0):

take `y_test.values()` and compare them directly with preds, treat both as numpy arrays and make comparisons, the predictions will definitely be in line with the actual data, indexes dont really define anything in this case, if you think that there is a mismatch between preds and y_test due to low accuracy, that is definitely a fault of the model or data or something else but the predictions match y_test

Comment: Unfortunately I can't even compare them as the y_test has indices in the format [2,25,456,12,13,505...etc.] while my pred array is just [0,1,2,3,4,5.. etc.] I could assume that a new array kept the order i.e. 2 - > 0 / 25 -> 1 etc. but I can't know for sure, right?

Comment: do `y_test = list(y_test.values())` and then you will be able to do a direct comparison without any problem